# Website offset to left in IE9

Tags: html, internet-explorer-9

I have a website, www.reviewmyapp.net. The site is fine in Firefox and Chrome, but in IE9 it is off to the side of the screen, and the text is not centered in the table.
I can't see what is wrong with it, and can't find any help on the web. Could someone have a look at it please? Many thanks.

Comment: Hi there! This question is not answerable in its current form. Without any HTML, css, context, or indication of what your site looks like, it is impossible to troubleshoot the trouble. If you could include some sample HTML, a jsFiddle that demonstrates the problem, or any other details, you will get better answers. Voting to close -- I suggest you edit your question to address the issues I've raised.

Comment: You might have missed it, but he provided the website link.

Comment: @alexvance It's hard to test when we don't have a reduced test case (ideally in a fiddle with relevant code copied here).

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. I gave you the URL, all you had to do was click on it and view source....  The other guys didn't mind answering me....

Comment: @Chris Gotcha, just saw this part" or indication of what your site looks like" and didn't know if you'd seen it.

Comment: @Kevmeister It isn't "noob bashing" -- you're taking it personally. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask "The other guys" tried to answer your question as it stands, but it is still a low-quality question without the details I very politely asked for. I didn't say "or no one will answer you, ever!", I said "you will get better answers". This is still true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can probably fix it with this header :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
```

Centering and floating problems that you have in IE9 and not in other browsers are often due to IE9 not really using the last (and most compatible) engine. This setting forces it to be the most compatible possible with current HTML norms.

But I can't test it myself (refer to Chris comments).

Comment: This answer would be a lot better if you explained what that is, what it does, and why it would address this very vague problem about which we know no details. For example, a link to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc288325%28v=vs.85%29.aspx might be a good start :)

Answer (score 1):

Adding `<!DOCTYPE html>` will fix this issue. You should always include this on every page because it tells the browser what version of HTML to render the page.

See this for more information: http://www.w3.org/QA/2002/04/valid-dtd-list.html

Answer (score 0):

From a look at your code in IE 9, it looks like you're missing a doctype declaration, as dystroy says. This is probably causing IE to lose closing tags, as almost none of the tags you use maintain their closing tags, leading to the actual issue. However, double check that you've closed all your tags as well. Post some actual code if you want more in-depth feedback.